# Execute hard coded command from Mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm looking for a way to execute a hard-coded Mongo update directly from my C# code. I know how to properly implement the scenario in C# but would love a way to be able to just drop a string in an execute it.

The following works on Robo and is what I'd like to execute it from C#:

```
db.getCollection('Routing').update(
{}, 
{
    $pull: {'Updates': {'RecordNumber': '33'}}
},
{
    "multi" : true
});
```

Is there a way to directly execute this from my C# code as a hard-coded string? 
I've experimented with BsonDocumentCommand and RunCommandAsync() but could not figure out a way to get it to execute an **update** as it doesn't appear to be designed for that.
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabaseBase_RunCommandAsync__1.htm

Am I missing some really obvious way to execute a hard-coded Mongo query using the C# driver?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick example of the kind of approach you can take. This doesn't cover the entire issue, but it's perhaps an avenue you could take to try to parse the entire command.

```
var cmd = "db.getCollection('Routing').update({ }, {  $pull: { 'Updates': { 'RecordNumber': '33'} } },{\"multi\" : true}); ";
// Part 0 = 'db', reject. Part 1 = getCollection('Routing'). Part 2 = update...
var parts = cmd.Split('.');

// Capitalize first letter to comply with C# naming, then get rid of the parameters
var function1 = parts[1].First().ToString().ToUpper() + parts[1].Substring(1).Split('(');
// Get contents of single-quotes
var param1 = parts[1].Split('\'')[1].Split('\'')[0];

var collection = (IMongoCollection<object>)db.GetType().GetMethod(function1).Invoke(db, new object[] { param1 });
```

Anyway, I'd recommend avoiding writing code parsers, especially if the command is hard-coded and won't change during runtime. If it's unavoidable, though, programmatic method invoking is the way to go. Just beware that the more complex the query can be, the more advanced the code to process it needs to be. Hope this helps!